# How to retrieve the context from the agent in Dialogflow

Tags: dialogflow-es, dialogflow-es-fulfillment

I have managed to retrieve the context variables from the webhook using [dialogflow-fulfillment](https://github.com/dialogflow/dialogflow-fulfillment-nodejs/blob/86a844a34ce61a665fa3687afe91af68b3dca0b8/src/contexts.js) `agent.context.get()` function however it does not provide the context variables that aren't set as input in that specific intent.

### Intent A: *"What city are you in?"*

- Through Dialogflow UI, the output context placeholder 'city' is set .
- User answers => "Montréal"
- Here I set the output context 'city' with the following code through the fulfiller:

`agent.context.set('city', 100, {cityName: "Montréal"})`

### Intent B: "When will it freeze?"

- Intentionally, no input/output context is set on Dialogflow. As I want the user to be able to ask this question without context.
- When the intent is matched, Dialogflow sends the following request to my fullfiler.

`{ "responseId": "496a4ed8-8421-4297-b464-adc54632cc93-32d6a6f2", "queryResult": { "queryText": "when will it freeze", "parameters": {}, "allRequiredParamsPresent": true, "fulfillmentText": "It will freeze next week", "fulfillmentMessages": [ { "text": { "text": [ "It will freeze next week" ] } } ], "intent": { "name": "projects/project-name/locations/global/agent/intents/7df0bb1d-f4ef-4e69-b9c4-4b6a2f91c95f", "displayName": "zone.freezing_dates via Fulfiller" }, "intentDetectionConfidence": 1, "diagnosticInfo": { "webhook_latency_ms": 59 }, "languageCode": "fr", "sentimentAnalysisResult": { "queryTextSentiment": { "score": 0.1, "magnitude": 0.1 } } }, "webhookStatus": { "message": "Webhook execution successful" }, "agentId": "5d8b71c7-cd3a-453a-b446-6d00334f1ae8" }`

As you can see, the context parameters aren't present in the webhook request even though the `city` parameter has been set by intent A).

Therefore, how do we retrieve the context variables from the user's session (and not from the intent's webhook)?

I have a feeling it has to do with the agent session path as described [here](https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-dialogflow/blob/05ea702372c08d0f0f157419799e59ea983df32a/samples/detect.js) but in this sample, it's part of the intent (again) as I expect a way to retrieve the agent context outside of the intent's scope.

I will also add as a note, I know the `city` context var exists because I can see it through the Dialogflow UI when I add it to the response text.

Comment: Can you please share further details about the issue you are facing so that I can give better solution.

Comment: @Aymal I just edited the post with more details. Thank you very much!